# Transposition cipher too long compilation

Tags: c, algorithm, optimization

I need to do a program that decodes Transposition cipher. On start I have one word, which is in encrypted text. the length of the key is equal to the -1 length of the received word. key is random.

Examples:

1. ```
   input text:Uniz isvrh tiesiime ffrmfbi jz tpywjhpf gx ucs zgvey eoj e igpg himua xgxfx qbxo xgw b xihapbx vftx jt xik jpxq pl eo owpygfrit zvjgrhri
   input word: mark
   output:They could scarcely believe it possible at two yards and a half below water mark was a regular rent in the form of an isosceles triangle
   ```
2. ```
   input text:Qr oc cvtmxen ev Rga Asto vlg uwiuxksp acw cx kxu lgmilv
   input word:was
   output:On my arrival at New York the question was at its height
   ```
3. ```
   input text: Rt kolniz qufkbnx R gjvoczkm zqk kgobzkwin ul cnn suwyckx
   input word: effect
   output:In effect however I admitted the existence of the monster
   ```

For examples 1 and 2 the program compiles quite quickly, but for example 3 
the program compiles for a very long time because i have too many for loops.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>


int main()
{
    unsigned int i = 0;
    int key[10];
    unsigned int k = 0;
    int check;
    unsigned int j, jj, jjj, jjjj, jjjjj, jjjjjj;
    int n = 50;
    char slowo[10];
    char plain[500], cipher[500];


    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Enter text:");
    fgets(plain, 500, stdin);
    printf("Enter word:");
    fgets(slowo, 500, stdin);

    if (strlen(slowo) == 4)
    {
        for (j = n; j != 0; j--)
        {
            key[0] = (j - 25);
            for (jj = n; jj != 0; jj--)
            {
                key[1] = (jj - 25);
                for (i = 0; i<strlen(plain); i++)
                {
                    if (isalpha(plain[i]))
                    {
                        if (islower(plain[i]))
                        {
                            check = plain[i];

                            if (islower(plain[i]) && check + key[k]>96 && check + key[k]<123)
                            {
                                cipher[i] = (plain[i] + key[k] - 'a') % 26 + 'a';
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                check = 123 + (check - 97 + key[k]);
                                cipher[i] = (check - 'a') % 26 + 'a';
                                check = 0;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            check = plain[i];
                            if (isupper(plain[i]) && check + key[k]>64 && check + key[k]<91)
                            {
                                cipher[i] = (plain[i] + key[k] - 'A') % 26 + 'A';
                            }

                            else
                            {
                                check = 91 + (check - 65 + key[k]);
                                cipher[i] = (check - 'A') % 26 + 'A';
                                check = 0;


                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                        if (isspace(plain[i]))
                        {
                            k--;


                            cipher[i] = plain[i];
                        }
                    k++;
                    if (k>strlen(slowo) - 3)//ostatniznak + \0
                        k = 0;
                }
                for (i = 0; i<strlen(plain); i++)
                {

                    if (isspace(cipher[i]) && cipher[i + 1] == slowo[0] && cipher[i + 2] == slowo[1] && cipher[i + 3] == slowo[2] && isspace(cipher[i + 4]))
                    {

                        cipher[strlen(plain) - 1] = '\0';
                        printf("%s", cipher);
                        return 0;

                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }

    if (strlen(slowo) == 5)
    {
        for (j = n; j != 0; j--)
        {
            key[0] = (j - 25);

            for (jj = n; jj != 0; jj--)
            {
                key[1] = (jj - 25);

                for (jjj = n; jjj != 0; jjj--)
                {
                    key[2] = (jjj - 25);

                    for (i = 0; i<strlen(plain); i++)
                    {
                        if (isalpha(plain[i]))
                        {
                            if (islower(plain[i]))
                            {
                                check = plain[i];

                                if (islower(plain[i]) && check + key[k]>96 && check + key[k]<123)
                                {
                                    cipher[i] = (plain[i] + key[k] - 'a') % 26 + 'a';
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    check = 123 + (check - 97 + key[k]);
                                    cipher[i] = (check - 'a') % 26 + 'a';
                                    check = 0;
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                check = plain[i];
                                if (isupper(plain[i]) && check + key[k]>64 && check + key[k]<91)
                                {
                                    cipher[i] = (plain[i] + key[k] - 'A') % 26 + 'A';
                                }

                                else
                                {
                                    check = 91 + (check - 65 + key[k]);
                                    cipher[i] = (check - 'A') % 26 + 'A';
                                    check = 0;


                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                            if (isspace(plain[i]))
                            {
                                k--;


                                cipher[i] = plain[i];
                            }
                        k++;
                        if (k>strlen(slowo) - 3)//ostatniznak + \0
                            k = 0;
                    }
                    for (i = 0; i<strlen(plain); i++)
                    {

                        if (isspace(cipher[i]) && cipher[i + 1] == slowo[0] && cipher[i + 2] == slowo[1] && cipher[i + 3] == slowo[2] && cipher[i + 4] == slowo[3] && isspace(cipher[i + 5]))
                        {
                            cipher[strlen(plain) - 1] = '\0';
                            printf("%s", cipher);
                            return 0;

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (strlen(slowo) == 6)
    {
        for (j = n; j != 0; j--)
        {
            key[0] = (j - 25);

            for (jj = n; jj != 0; jj--)
            {
                key[1] = (jj - 25);
                for (jjj = n; jjj != 0; jjj--)
                {
                    key[2] = (jjj - 25);
                    for (jjjj = n; jjjj != 0; jjjj--)
                    {
                        key[3] = (jjjj - 25);
                        for (i = 0; i<strlen(plain); i++)
                        {
                            if (isalpha(plain[i]))
                            {
                                if (islower(plain[i]))
                                {
                                    check = plain[i];

                                    if (islower(plain[i]) && check + key[k]>96 && check + key[k]<123)
                                    {
                                        cipher[i] = (plain[i] + key[k] - 'a') % 26 + 'a';
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        check = 123 + (check - 97 + key[k]);
                                        cipher[i] = (check - 'a') % 26 + 'a';
                                        check = 0;
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    check = plain[i];
                                    if (isupper(plain[i]) && check + key[k]>64 && check + key[k]<91)
                                    {
                                        cipher[i] = (plain[i] + key[k] - 'A') % 26 + 'A';
                                    }

                                    else
                                    {
                                        check = 91 + (check - 65 + key[k]);
                                        cipher[i] = (check - 'A') % 26 + 'A';
                                        check = 0;


                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            else
                                if (isspace(plain[i]))
                                {
                                    k--;


                                    cipher[i] = plain[i];
                                }
                            k++;
                            if (k>strlen(slowo) - 3)//ostatniznak + \0
                                k = 0;
                        }
                        for (i = 0; i<strlen(plain); i++)
                        {

                            if (isspace(cipher[i]) && cipher[i + 1] == slowo[0] && cipher[i + 2] == slowo[1] && cipher[i + 3] == slowo[2] && cipher[i + 4] == slowo[3] && cipher[i + 5] == slowo[4] && isspace(cipher[i + 6]))
                            {
                                cipher[strlen(plain) - 1] = '\0';
                                printf("%s", cipher);
                                return 0;

                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }

        }
    }
    if (strlen(slowo) == 7)
    {
        for (j = n; j != 0; j--)
        {
            key[0] = (j - 25);
            for (jj = n; jj != 0; jj--)
            {
                key[1] = (jj - 25);
                if (isspace(cipher[i]) && cipher[i + 1] == slowo[0] && cipher[i + 2] == slowo[1] && isspace(cipher[i + 7]))
                {
                    jj--;
                }

                for (jjj = n; jjj != 0; jjj--)
                {
                    key[2] = (jjj - 25);

                    for (jjjj = n; jjjj != 0; jjjj--)
                    {
                        key[3] = (jjjj - 25);


                        for (jjjjj = n; jjjjj != 0; jjjjj--)
                        {
                            key[4] = (jjjjj - 25);

                            for (i = 0; i<strlen(plain); i++)
                            {
                                if (isalpha(plain[i]))
                                {
                                    if (islower(plain[i]))
                                    {
                                        check = plain[i];

                                        if (islower(plain[i]) && check + key[k]>96 && check + key[k]<123)
                                        {
                                            cipher[i] = (plain[i] + key[k] - 'a') % 26 + 'a';
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            check = 123 + (check - 97 + key[k]);
                                            cipher[i] = (check - 'a') % 26 + 'a';
                                            check = 0;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        check = plain[i];
                                        if (isupper(plain[i]) && check + key[k]>64 && check + key[k]<91)
                                        {
                                            cipher[i] = (plain[i] + key[k] - 'A') % 26 + 'A';
                                        }

                                        else
                                        {
                                            check = 91 + (check - 65 + key[k]);
                                            cipher[i] = (check - 'A') % 26 + 'A';
                                            check = 0;


                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                    if (isspace(plain[i]))
                                    {
                                        k--;


                                        cipher[i] = plain[i];
                                    }
                                k++;
                                if (k>strlen(slowo) - 3)//ostatniznak + \0
                                    k = 0;
                            }
                            for (i = 0; i<strlen(plain); i++)
                            {

                                if (isspace(cipher[i]) && cipher[i + 1] == slowo[0] && cipher[i + 2] == slowo[1] && cipher[i + 3] == slowo[2] && cipher[i + 4] == slowo[3] && cipher[i + 5] == slowo[4] && cipher[i + 6] == slowo[5] && isspace(cipher[i + 7]))
                                {
                                    cipher[strlen(plain) - 1] = '\0';
                                    printf("%s", cipher);
                                    return 0;

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (strlen(slowo) == 8)
    {
        for (j = n; j != 0; j--)
        {
            key[0] = (j - 25);
            for (jj = n; jj != 0; jj--)
            {
                key[1] = (jj - 25);

                for (jjj = n; jjj != 0; jjj--)
                {
                    key[2] = (jjj - 25);
                    for (jjjj = n; jjjj != 0; jjjj--)
                    {
                        key[3] = (jjjj - 25);


                        for (jjjjj = n; jjjjj != 0; jjjjj--)
                        {

                            key[4] = (jjjjj - 25);

                            for (jjjjjj = 0; jjjjjj != 0; jjjjjj--)
                            {
                                key[5] = (jjjjjj - 25);
                                for (i = 0; i<strlen(plain); i++)
                                {
                                    if (isalpha(plain[i]))
                                    {
                                        if (islower(plain[i]))
                                        {
                                            check = plain[i];

                                            if (islower(plain[i]) && check + key[k]>96 && check + key[k]<123)
                                            {
                                                cipher[i] = (plain[i] + key[k] - 'a') % 26 + 'a';
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                check = 123 + (check - 97 + key[k]);
                                                cipher[i] = (check - 'a') % 26 + 'a';
                                                check = 0;
                                            }
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            check = plain[i];
                                            if (isupper(plain[i]) && check + key[k]>64 && check + key[k]<91)
                                            {
                                                cipher[i] = (plain[i] + key[k] - 'A') % 26 + 'A';
                                            }

                                            else
                                            {
                                                check = 91 + (check - 65 + key[k]);
                                                cipher[i] = (check - 'A') % 26 + 'A';
                                                check = 0;


                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else
                                        if (isspace(plain[i]))
                                        {
                                            k--;


                                            cipher[i] = plain[i];
                                        }
                                    k++;
                                    if (k>strlen(slowo) - 3)//ostatniznak + \0
                                        k = 0;
                                }
                                for (i = 0; i<strlen(plain); i++)
                                {

                                    if (isspace(cipher[i]) && cipher[i + 1] == slowo[0] && cipher[i + 2] == slowo[1] && cipher[i + 3] == slowo[2] && cipher[i + 4] == slowo[3] && cipher[i + 5] == slowo[4] && cipher[i + 6] == slowo[5] && cipher[i + 7] == slowo[6] && isspace(cipher[i + 7]))
                                    {
                                        cipher[strlen(plain) - 1] = '\0';
                                        printf("%s", cipher);
                                        return 0;

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        printf("Error");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

I would like to optimize the code to make it faster, but I have no idea.

Comment: You're using a too brutal brute force algorithm. You may want to check out the Babbage-Kasiski decryption method. You'll end up with several candidate keys, but chances are overwhelming that only one will lead to your known word (what's called a *crib*) appearing in the decrypted text. You might also want to query the Security Stack Exchange site.

Comment: `j`, `jj`, `jjj`, `jjjj`, `jjjjj`, `jjjjjj` are awful variable names. `fflush(stdin)` has undefined behavior (`fflush` is write operation, `stdin` is an input stream).

Comment: This belongs on codereview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some possible optimizations - what is called a *keyhole optimization* - in your code, but I'd rather change the *algorithm* you're using. Keyhole optimizations are penny wise and pound foolish, and [premature optimization is the root of all evil](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth). *Decreasing the algorithm complexity* is almost always your top priority. Then and only then you do further optimizations.

Here you know that key length is (in the third example) five, because the *crib* `effect` is six characters; we'll refer to the key as 12345.

We align the key to the cyphertext since whitespaces are ignored:

```
12 345123 4512345 1 23451234 512 345123451 23 451 2345123
Rt kolniz qufkbnx R gjvoczkm zqk kgobzkwin ul cnn suwyckx
```

We *could* now implement a brute-force Babbage decryption in [O(n<sup>3</sup>)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations#Matrix_algebra) using a linear equation system:

```
x1 - 1 = R
x2 - 2 = t
x3 - 3 = k
x4 - 4 = o
x5 - 5 = l
x6 - 1 = n
...
x48 - 3 = x
```

But we can rather observe that **we only have one word** whose length is equal to that of 'effect' - it is 'kolniz'. **Which means that we can recover the key straight away**: it is the difference "nikol - efeec". The first symbol, 1, equals to a shift forward from the second `e` of *effect* to the `n` of *kolniz*, that is, 9 positions. So when we find a letter mapped to the 1 symbol of the *worm*, such as the first 'R', we go back 9 positions from R, and we find 'I'.

The above algorithm is roughly O(n+m) with n being the length of the ciphertext and m being the length of the key.

Suppose we have two  words whose length is equal to "effect", say they are "abcdef" and "ghijkl". Which one do we use?

Hypothesis 1: abcdef is the cyphertext of effect. If that is true then the shift for the first symbol of 'e' is 'a' and the *same* shift must get 'f' into 't'.

Hypothesis 2: ghikl is the cyphertext of effect. If that is true then the shift for the first symbol of 'e' is 'g' and the *same* shift must get 'l' into 't'.

The chances of both hypotheses being true and us not being able which one is correct are those of *another word* having the same shift difference in its first and last letters as are 'e' and 't' in our crib, for example the first word is 'effect' and the other is "cougar", "dirges", "harlow", or "jalopy". Those chances are very little.

Comment: Did you mean [peephole optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peephole_optimization)?

Comment: @JimMischel Yes, of course. English betrays me at times 